# Touch pan gesture isn't translated to WM_VSCROLL in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, windows-8, touch, gesture

I'm working on implementing native Windows touch support in a legacy WinForms app for .NET 4.0+. The app is being developed in VS 2013, and the main test system is Win 8.1 Pro. Doing this in a custom control, which is a descendant of the Control class.

According to the [Windows Touch Gestures Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MSDN article, "the default gesture handler maps some gestures to Windows messages that were used in previous versions of Windows" (see the 'Legacy Support' subsection). However, in my tests the basic pan gesture one can use to scroll a control in the vertical direction using one finger, isn't translated to WM_VSCROLL. The protected OnMouseWheel method isn't also raised.

Have I missed any important settings or anything else we need to turn on to enable this default mapping for the basic touch gestures?

Answer (score 1):

I have test it on windows 10. Window without WS_VSCROLL style will not receive the legacy WM_VSCROLL for touch pan gesture.

You need to translate itself, but it is very simple. Handle WM_GESTURE in your custom control's wndproc and translate the `GID_PAN` action to WM_VSCROLL should do the work.